# What does "spökerisch" mean?

Tags: meaning, german-to-english, dialect

If the gentleman with the Rheinisches Wörterbuch could help again...
*Spökerisch* is from Heinrich Böll and thus quite possibly Rhenish again. It might mean *potty* or *dim* or *eccentric* from context.

> (Er) war nicht gerade ein Spinner, aber doch ein bisschen spökerisch.

Comment: Also see [spökig](http://plattmakers.de/en/7278/spökelig), [spöken](http://plattmakers.de/en/1676/spöken). And you can access the Rheinisches Wörterbuch yourself. [Spök](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/RhWB/?sigle=RhWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=RS21466#XRS21471)

Answer (score 4):

The word probably stems from "Plattdeutsch", a dialect (or even an own language) spoken in Northern Germany.

They know the word [Spökenkieker](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sp%C3%B6kenkieker) — people who can tell the future (mostly bad events coming up) or see ghosts. "Spuk-Gucker" or "Geister-Seher" would be a direct translation. Sometimes people who tell scary stories also are called *Spökenkieker*.

*Spöken* are ghosts or spooks (see the similarity?), so somebody who is *spökerisch* might be a bit spooky or strange.